# What are non-categorical theories about?

Tags: logic, model-theory

With theories that are categorical, it seems like you could say that the theory is about collections of objects (numbers, points, etc.) with a certain structure (the structure the standard models have). For instance, second-order $\mathsf{PA}$ seems to be about collections of elements ordered by a successor function such that there is a first element and no last, with addition and multiplication defined over the elements.  Even with $k$-categorical theories, it seems like you could understand the theory as being about a given structure, once you fix the cardinality.

But what about theories that don't seem to have any intended interpretation? What should I think something like group theory is *about*? It isn't about systems of elements with a certain structure---since the structures studied are too varied. But then what is it about?

Is there a more general way of understanding what a mathematical theory is about that generalizes to non-categorical theories?

Comment: In general, a (consistent) theory "is about" whatever satisfy the axioms of the theory. For *categorical* theory, all its model are isomorphic: thus, we may say that all its model are "indistinguishible" from one another. For non-categorical ones (like f-o arithmetic) there are way "to distinguish" different models that are **not** avialable to the corresponding f-o theory.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I suppose another way of putting my question is: is there something that unites the models of a non-categorical theory in the same way that isomorphism unites the models of a categorical theory? So that we could say, e.g., "oh group theory is about models with *these* properties"---just like we can say (2nd-o) PA is about models with *this* structure.

Comment: Nor more and nor less than the "properties" expressed by the axioms, i.e. a [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29) "is a set of elements [whatever] together with an operation that combines any two of its elements to form a third element satisfying four conditions called the group axioms, namely : closure, associativity, identity and invertibility."

Comment: A theory can have an intended interpretation without being categorical - for example Peano Arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give a partial answer to the question (as it was reformulated in the comments).

When moving away from ($\kappa$-)categorical theories, a natural next step in generality would be to consider complete first order theories $T$ . In this case, any two models of $T$ are elementary equivalent (not necessarily isomorphic).

The structural *link* between two models of $T$ is now given by the [Keisler-Shelah Theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Keisler-Shelah_isomorphism_theorem): they must have isomorphic ultrapowers.